# Thruster effect using particle engine

Tags: c#, xna, particle-engine

I've been trying to make a sort of thruster effect for a spaceship using a particle engine and I can't seem to get the effect i'm looking for. I followed this tutorial for the particle engine: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/2d-particle-engine-1

I want the particle to go inwards rather than out. Something like this but with the particles not a static image:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKULU.png

or something along these lines:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czgWZwUld_Y

Comment: What you managed so far looks pretty good. But what does "inwards rather than out" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the **angularVelocity** and the **Size** for a bigger value.(sorry for my bad english)
I dont know how the: **public void Update()** is working but...try this too:

```
public void Update()
    {
        TTL--;
        Position += Velocity + 1;//or other value...test it!
        Angle += AngularVelocity;
    }
```

Comment: I've managed to figure it out but thank you for your suggestion. I took the velocity of the particles and multiplied it by the velocity of the ship which gave me exactly what I wanted.